# How to save scikit learn randomforest in json format to store in the database?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, mysql-connector

How to save a randomforest model trained using scikit in json format? I have used pickle, cPickle, joblib and tried to store the pickled file in the database.
All of them work for decision tree but for random forest it gives sql broken pipe error.

1st:

```
pickledFile = _pickle.dumps(random_forest_model)
```

2nd:

```
pickledFile = joblib.dump(random_forest_model, "forest")

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO models(model) VALUES (_binary%s);",(pickledFile))
conn.commit()
```

3rd:

```
with open('screening_forest.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickledFile = _pickle.dump(random_forest_model, f)
#used %s
```

Is it because of the memory? If I use randomized cv or grid search, how should I save the model?

If I have to store it in a json format how should I do that for random forest?
What sql type should I use (%s)?
What is the type used by scikit learn for ml models?

Comment: maybe it's new but pickle.dumps(rf) works for me :)